# GDB remote debugging OS, CS segment issue

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, gdb, qemu

I have very specific issue with debugging my own bootable OS.
I use GDB - QEMU tandem for debugging the operating system I have (not so much I have).
In bootstrap assembly, I am able to debug with GDB up to the point when I switch to protected mode i.e. change segment register values (specifically Code Segment register value).
When %CS register value is changed, I get my trace lost of the debugging information, and, thus, GDB becomes unable to serve to its purpose.

So I was wandering back and forth of the internet, yet could not find the solution on how to handle this segment switch within debugger (GDB).
Any hints or resources will be appreciated.

Comment: Bochs has a built-in debugger that understands segmentation and knows what mode the CPU is in.  (And can pretty-print GDT and page tables so you can check you put the right things in them.)  IDK if it can record a trace to allow stepping backwards or something if that's what you're trying to do with GDB.  https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html / https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/debugger-gui.html / https://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs